# switching servers in a load balancer in azure through api

Tags: load-balancing, azure, update, azure-networking

We have a long and heavy process which updates in memory catalogs for clients. while it happens, clients with large catalogs are experiencing low performance. I am looking for a way to turn on a VM, run the process on it, add it to the load balancer and removing other VMs on it using some kind of a web service or api of Azure.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PowerShell to reconfigure the load balancer and remote PowerShell to execute any process remotely. Additionally, use automation to automate the process.

**Update an existing load balancer**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-internet-arm-ps#update-an-existing-load-balancer

**WinRM**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-winrm

**Automation First Runbook**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell